# Does Groovy have an annotation for block-level synchronization?

Tags: multithreading, groovy, synchronization

I love the [@Synchronized](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Synchronized.html) annotation that Groovy provides. [It is a safer option](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK00-J.+Use+private+final+lock+objects+to+synchronize+classes+that+may+interact+with+untrusted+code) than the 'synchronized' keyword for Java since it uses a local / private lock variable rather than the 'this' object. However in Groovy all rules can be broken. :)

I also know there is Lombok, a Java library that [provides the same feature](https://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized.html).

But is there a way to use an annotation within a method so that some of the method's code is not synchronized (for better performance) and other parts are (out of necessity)?

While I was typing this question I may have come up with one solution to my own question:

- Extract method: create a new method, move the block of code that needs synchronization into that method. The original code calls the new method. New method has @Synchronized.

Does that sound right? Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there a way to use an annotation within a method so that some
>   of the method's code is not synchronized (for better performance) and
>   other parts are (out of necessity)?

No, there is not.  The approach you described as an option would work.